# Accessing the values returned from a cursor

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the values returned by a cursor:

```
competence = cursor.execute(SELECT)
print competence
```

Output:

```
<fdb.fbcore.Cursor object at 0x1051c3cc0>
```

How can I access the values returned by `cursor.execute`? I'm using python 2, so I can't use unpacking (`*`).

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute` loads a generator into the cursor. You don't assign the result of the `execute` call. You can either iterate over the cursor, or use `fetchone/fetchall()`.

```
cursor.execute(SELECT)
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

Or

```
cursor.execute(SELECT)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```